# Is storing a byte in a void pointer cross-platform safe?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, platform-agnostic

```
void *vp = (void *)5;
uint8_t i = (uint8_t)vp;
```

Will i == 5 on all 8-bit and higher cpus? What are the risks doing this? Is there a better way to have a variable store either an 8-bit integer literal or a pointer in C99?

I have an array of function pointers to functions that take a void *. Some functions need to interpret the void * as a uint8_t.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The correct way to do it is with a union that contains a `void *` and a `uint8_t`. That's what unions are for.

Comment: If you want to store it in an integer type, use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: `warning: initialization of ‘void *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast` so says GCC, and that's without explicitly enabling any warnings. Also as per @dbush comment, could you expand your question a bit as it is not clear what you are trying to do or why.

Comment: If you're trying to pass this value as a parameter to a thread function, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: How does the function know whether the argument is a `void *` or a `uint8_t`? Or to put it another way, what is the function signature?

Comment: @user3386109: Context.  Using `void *` as the type for a user-defined callback parameter is a very common idiom.  You've registered the callback function passing this as the user-defined. parameter, so the callback function knows what to do with it when called with it.   I believe the rationale is that `void *` is big enough to hold any pointer type you care to cast it into.

Comment: Improved explanation.

Comment: @marko Yes, that's fine if the callbacks all take a pointer as the argument, and use the pointer as a pointer. I've not seen callbacks where the parameter is either a pointer, or some other arbitrary type. That's not a standard idiom, it's more commonly known as spaghetti code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void *vp = 5;` should not compile; the C standard at least requires the compiler to issue a diagnostic message. You can request the conversion with `void *vp = (void *) 5;`, and you can request the reverse conversion with `(uint8_t) vp`. The C standard does not guarantee this will reproduce the original value. (Conversions involving pointers are specified in C 2018 6.3.2.3.) It is likely to work in most C implementations.

An alternative that would be defined by the C standard would be to use offsets into some sufficiently large object you already have. For example, if you have some array `A`, and you want to store some small number `n` in a `void *`, then you can do:

```
void *vp = (char *) A + n; // Point n bytes into the object A.
```

and you can recover the number with:

```
(char *) vp - (char *) A // Subtract base address to recover offset.
```

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I suspect the condition for 'works in most implementations' is that the CPU is capable of storing both an integral type and an address in a general purpose register without having to go via memory for a conversion - in which case endianness might bite you.   You'd probably have to try hard to find one where it *didn't* work.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does allow for conversions between an integer and a pointer, however it doesn't explain exactly how it should happen.  That is left up to each specific implementation.

Section 6.3.2.3 p5-6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes these conversions:

> *5* An  integer  may  be  converted  to  any  pointer  type.   Except  as  previously  specified,  the result  is  implementation-defined,
> might  not  be  correctly  aligned,  might  not  point  to  an entity
> of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> *6* Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type.  Except as previously specified, the result  is  implementation-defined.  If  the
> result  cannot  be  represented  in  the  integer  type,the  behavior
> is  undefined.  The  result  need  not  be  in  the  range  of  values
> of  any integer type.

Under gcc in particular what you're doing will work, however it's not guaranteed to work on all compilers or architectures.

What *is* guaranteed to work however is to take the address of a compound literal:

```
void *vp = &(uint8_t){5};
uint8_t i = *(uint8_t *)vp;
```

This creates a temporary object of type `uint8_t` and takes its address.  This address can then be converted to a `void *` and back which is fully standard compliant, as per paragraph 1 of 6.3.2.3:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.  **A pointer to any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a  pointer  to `void` and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal to the original pointer.**

The lifetime of the compound literal is that of the block in which it is defined.  So as long the pointer isn't used after that block ends it will work.

If however you intend to pass it to a function that starts a thread, you're better off dynamically allocating memory for the value and passing that.  Otherwise, you run the risk of the function where the compound literal is defined returning while the thread function is running which could attempt to use that pointer.

Comment: _Under gcc in particular what you're doing will work_ Except that GCC doc says it is UB.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  It is not.  See [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation).